# How to get fresh image from resource?

Tags: java, html

Suppose I have two links on a web-page. And suppose theirs `href` tags are the same. If I click the first link I'll get an image (most important that `GetFromService` will be executed). Now if I click the second link, which targets the same image name, I'll get the image from cache, not from the resourse. How to get fresh image from resource? (Actually I need before the images will be returned the `GetFromService` should be executed even if the images are the same.)

```
<a href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/GetFromService?n=<c:out value="${object.name}"/>&opt=makeobtained' rel="lightbox" title='' > 
    <img src='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/GetFromService?n=<c:out value="${object.name}"/>&s=1'>
</a>
```

I tried use caching like this but it does nor work:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
```

Comment: How about a random parameter ?random="+System.currentTimeMillis ();  that would make individual url for each image, so caching should not apply

Comment: @Jan it really works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a random parameter `?random="+System.currentTimeMillis ();` that would make individual url for each image, so caching should not apply